# How to redirect to a dynamic route after user register for the first time in Laravel 7

Tags: laravel-7

I am new to Laravel and using Laravel 7, I want to ask that, when a new user register for the first time a verification email is sent to his/her inbox and when he verifies it, must be redirected to a route like the edit profile page to complete the registration process... something like:

```php
route('user/ . $user->id . / edit');
```

Im not sure if I should edit this page, if so how? because it redirects to the HOME

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\VerifiesEmails;

class VerificationController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Email Verification Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller is responsible for handling email verification for any
    | user that recently registered with the application. Emails may also
    | be re-sent if the user didn't receive the original email message.
    |
    */

    use VerifiesEmails;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after verification.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = RouteServiceProvider::HOME;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
        $this->middleware('signed')->only('verify');
        $this->middleware('throttle:6,1')->only('verify', 'resend');
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can change it from `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php` :

```php
public const HOME = '/home';
```

to,

```php
public const HOME = '/dashboard';
```

Then it will throw you to the `/dashboard`